# Check if a ListView has an specific a number of items, and scroll to last one with Espresso

Tags: android, integration-testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to implement this using [Google's Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/), however I'm not finding any `ViewAssertion` or `ViewAction` that'd allow me to do this.

I'm not sure if these can be done using bundled in matchers or should I write my own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though @denys answer seemed to be correct at first glance, it looks like it works only on certain cases (as suggested by [Espresso author](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-test-kit-discuss/k50qXMmJ2BI/VopQpvl40ygJ)). The proper way to scroll to an specific item is as replied here on [android-test-kit-discuss](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-test-kit-discuss/k50qXMmJ2BI/pZs-dXskC40J) forum, and reproduced below:

```
onData(instanceOf(Item.class))
            .inAdapterView(allOf(withId(android.R.id.list), isDisplayed()))
            .atPosition(9)
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Answer (score 1):

It could look something like this:

**1. Find the number of elements in listView and save it in some variable**:

```
    final int[] counts = new int[1]; 
    onView(withId(R.id.some_list_view)).check(matches(new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            ListView listView = (ListView) view;

            counts[0] = listView.getCount();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {

        }
    }));
```

**2. Then, knowing the number of elements in listView you can scroll to any element within the range.**

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(R.id.some_list_view).getPosition(<item_index>).perform(scrollTo())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have this specific number then you have do something like this:

```
onData(is(instanceOf(yourClass.class)))
    .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.some_list_view))
    .atPosition(spicificNumber)
    .perform(scrollTo());
```

This will fail if ListView doesn't have an item at position with specificNumber.

EDITED:

Take a look also at this example - [Espresso samples](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSamples#Asserting_that_a_data_item_is_not_in_an_adapter). It will help you to check if there are no more items in the list after spesificNumber.